# Cordova app stopped playing audio on background after some minutes on Android

Tags: android, cordova, audio

I have built a Cordova 8 app with a playing stream. If the app runs in the background (the device is sleeping), the audio still playing but after some minutes (4 or 5) is stopped.

This is only happening on Android and the player object is an audio-element on the index.html file.

It's only happening when the device runs on battery. It looks like the Android set app in stand-by when sleeping and the device running on battery.

How to prevent this? Using the cordova-plugin-media isn't the solution because of compressing stream (aac).

Comment: i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it using *cordova-plugin-background-mode* plugin
and adding this to the config.xml:

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
        </config-file>
```

Comment: Thank you. The installation of plugin 'cordova-plugin-background-mode' fails for Cordova 9. I use this tip for installing: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/441. 
Also, WAKE_LOCK will also be added by the plugin. For REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION I add it to plugin.xml.